# How can I compile and run C++ on Mac using Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, atom-editor

I'm new to C++ and trying to compile and run C++ code to no avail. Please help!
Below is a screenshot of my code in Xcode. But Run is not available. I've also tried to compile and run in Atom after installing g++ compiler and got errors. Help!

[image: Xcode]
[image: Atom]

[image: gpp compiler]

Comment: In the Atom editor, the middle of those error "boxes" are build errors because you have errors in your code that you need to fix.

Comment: "use of undeclared identifier `std` " that sounds as if you are compiling as C not as C++. Try to invoke the compiler from the command line, before you let an IDE do everything in background

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by invoke the compiler from the command line?

Comment: How do you even invoke the compiler from the editor? What is your configuration? What are the commands that the editor runs to build your program? Do you have a `Makefile`? What does it look like?

Comment: no need to create a command line c++ project and add your file to it. xcode doesn't support compiling/running standalone files

Comment: I've added screenshot of the C++ compiler I installed in Atom. Supposedly, I should have Xcode installed - and the editor would be able to compile and run C++ in itself.

Comment: If you have gcc installed, what output do you get when you do `gcc main.cpp` ?

Comment: U mean run ```gcc main.cpp``` in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new project.

In Xcode:

1. Select: "File" / "New" / "Project" (window pops up)
2. Choose "macOS" in top tabs
3. Select "Command line tool"
4. Press "Next" button
5. Provide:

   - "product name", for example "my awesome app"
   - "Organization name" (you can type here your name)
   - "Organization id" (something like reversed host name, for example: `us.home.<yourName>`)
   - select "Language C++"
6. Press "Next" button
7. Select directory where project should be created

If you prefer something more universal (multi platform) take a look on `cmake` tool which allows to handle almost any IDE.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I ran it per your instructions and got error use of undeclared identifier 'std'. Although in my MOOC lecture, instructor was using it and I have the exact same code.

Comment: Ask new question providing all needed details. For now it looks like some missing `#include` like `#include<iostream>`.